# How do I use gems with Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, capistrano

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 9.04 and I have issues using gems.
I installed Ruby, Rubygems and Rails using apt-get.
The `rails` command does work.

I then installed capistrano and other gems, such as heroku. 
In order to do that, I used the command:

```
sudo gem install XXX
```

When I want to use the `cap` command it does not work:

```
bash: cap: command not found
```

It is the same with the other gem commands.

Do I have something particular to do so that the gem commands work?

Comment: isn't this question more suitable asked in http://superuser.com/?

Comment: @ThiagoDiniz or in [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/)?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

### Where are my Gems?

You can find where your gems are stored using the `gem environment` command. For example:

```
chris@chris-laptop:~$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.2

  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i486-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/chris/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
```

If you look at the "GEM PATHS:" section you can see that gems can be stored in two places on my laptop: `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8` or in the `.gem` directory in my home dir.

You can also see that executables are stored in EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY which in this case is `/usr/bin`.

Because `/usr/bin` is in my path this lets me run `cap`, `merb`, `rails` etc.

#### Updating your PATH

If for some reason your EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY isn't on your path (for example if it is /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin) then you need to update your PATH variable.

Assuming that you are using the bash shell. You can do this quickly for the current session by typing the following at the shell prompt; let's pretend that you want to add `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin` to the path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

and press return. That appends the new directory to the end of the current path. Note the colon between `$PATH` and `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`

To set the value for all sessions you will need to edit either your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file and add the same line to the end of the file. I usually edit my `.bashrc` file for no reason other than that's what I've always done. When finished, save the file and then refresh your environment by typing:

```
bash
```

at the shell prompt. That will cause the `.bashrc` to get reread.

At any point you can check the current value of `$PATH` by typing

```
echo $PATH
```

at the shell prompt.

Here's a sample from one of my own servers, where my username is "chris" and the machine name is "chris-laptop":

```
chris@chris-laptop:~$ 
chris@chris-laptop:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
chris@chris-laptop:~$ 
chris@chris-laptop:~$ export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
chris@chris-laptop:~$ 
chris@chris-laptop:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
chris@chris-laptop:~$
```

### My Gem won't load!

"[Ruby gems won't load even though installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792080/ruby-gems-wont-load-even-though-installed/3793059#3793059)" highlights a common problem using multiple different versions of Ruby; Sometimes the Gem environment and Gem path get out of sync:

```
rb(main):003:0> Gem.path

=> ["/opt/ruby1.9/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1"]
irb(main):004:0> exit
```

Any Ruby process here is looking only in one place for its Gems.

```
:~/$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.1 (2009-05-12 patchlevel 129) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/ruby1.9/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/ruby1.9/bin/ruby1.9
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/ruby1.9/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/ruby1.9/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/mark/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Look carefully at the output of gem environment:

```
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/ruby1.9/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
```

This isn't the same path as returned by Gem.path:

```
["/opt/ruby1.9/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1"]
```

It's hard to say what exactly caused `lib/ruby` to change to `lib/ruby1.9` but most likely the developer was working with multiple Ruby versions. A quick `mv` or `ln` will solve the problem.

If you do need to work with multiple Ruby versions then you really should be using [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).

Comment: How can I edit my $PATH so that it includes the two directory where the gems are installed ? Thanks

Comment: I did that :    
sudo ln -s /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.5/bin/cap /usr/local/bin/cap
   
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/cap': File exists   
But it does not work ! 
It still get :
bash: cap: command not found

Here is my $PATH:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/real/RealPlayer:/var/lib/gems/1.8:/home/arthur/.gem/ruby/1.8

Comment: Now it works. I changed the path to:
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/home/arthur/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin

Comment: Is there a way to change the EXECUTABLE_DIRECTORY to something more standard, like /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin? Adding /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin to my path doesn't sit well, particularly since it has a version number in it.

Comment: When I wanted to change that on a system level I had to change that at `/etc/environment`

Comment: Typing `bash` doesn't actually refresh your environment; it just opens a new shell in the current terminal. (You can even get back to the original shell using Ctrl-D.) It's true that the new environment includes the information from the updated `.bashrc` file, but what you really want is to source the file to update the current shell: `$ . ~/.bashrc`. (You can also use the `source` command, but `.` is shorter.)

Answer (score 5):

As noted by @Chris you need to add the gems environment to your path. You can do this by:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin' | tee --append ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

The folder in which gems are *stored* must be on your PATH, for example mine is:

> /home/victor/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin

Check your path by typing

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Here is the content of ~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin :
activerecord-2.3.2  activesupport-2.3.2  heroku-0.9.1  json-1.1.6  rails-2.3.2

When I install capistrano from my home folder ~, it does not go in this folder.
Furthermore, the heroku gem is in the right folder but the heroku command does not work.

Also here is what the $PATH command returns:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: Does your rails gem work? Please add your folder ~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin to the path and give a try

Comment: I asked a question in order to know how to edit the $PATH:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910088/how-can-i-edit-the-path-
on-linux

Answer (score 1):

It seens that when installing rubygems, now in ubuntu 9.04, I have this problem. I noticed that in "gem environment" the executable directory is "/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin", instead of "/usr/bin"... This is a problem with rubygems or with ubuntu 9.04??

The solution that I encountered is to add "/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin" to my $PATH doing this:
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
But it don't is saved... how can I save my path?

Thanks...

Resolvi: coloquei o export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin no ~/.bashrc! =]

Comment: To save the path, check out the other question I asked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910088/how-can-i-edit-the-path-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

mkmf is part of the ruby1.9.1-dev package. This package contains the header files needed for extension libraries for Ruby 1.9.1. You need to install the ruby1.9.1-dev package by doing:

sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev