# Can't get curb-fu Ruby gem to load properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm stumped on a problem that others on SO and around the web have been having, but whose answers don't seem to be working for me.

Trying to use the curb-fu gem, which a wrapper around the curb gem. Here's what I've tried:

- gem list shows that curb and curb-fu are installed
- i've added: gem 'curb' and gem 'curb-fu' to my Gemfile and run bundle install
- i've uninstalled the gem files and tried restarting
- i've uninstalled libcurl3, libcurl3-gnutls, and libcurl4-openssl-dev
- load up a rails console, require curb-fu, and i can create an instance of CurbFu
- load up irb, require curb-fu, and i can create an instance of CurbFu

In my app, at the top of my file, I:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'curb-fu'
```

And I get: no such file to load -- curb-fu

What the heck am I doing wrong?  The only thing I can think of is that curb-fu has a dependency on curb, which, according to it's [github page](https://github.com/taf2/curb), has only been tested on GNU/Linux x86.  I'm running Ubuntu Linux x86-64.  I doubt that's it, but just wanted to bring it up.

Any ideas?

**Update**: 
I ran:

```
sudo find / -name "rubygems" -print
```

and the output was:

```
/root/rubygems-1.7.2/test/rubygems
/root/rubygems-1.7.2/test/rubygems/rubygems
/root/rubygems-1.7.2/lib/rubygems
/usr/share/doc/rubygems
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems
```

Could that be the issue?

**Update 2**
Based off of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792080/ruby-gems-wont-load-even-though-installed) I checked 'Gem.path' and 'gem env' and they're both pointing to the same place:

```
irb(main):003:0> Gem.path
=> ["/home/kf/.gem/ruby/1.8", "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"]

gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.7.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/kf/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted the server, and everything works.  Only other thing I tried before that was updating my path to include my main gem path, /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8.  This solution feels awful, but hey, I'm up and running.