# problem in bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I already gem bundler in system. I check "gem list". it show:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (1.0.3)
```

but I go to app and execute "bundle install". it is show:

```
bundle: command not found
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have not set your gem_home path in your shell variable $PATH...

Try (with your own correct path) in your shell:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

Maybe this helps you further: [How do I use gems with Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909673/gems-and-ubuntu-9-04)