# How to change the Bundle Installer Executable and Installation directory

Tags: installation, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle

I have installed RVM and as noted in the install http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ I was able to get  "rvm is a function."

A lot of what I've read recommends not to use sudo gem install bundler, but it did not work without sudo (the error said I was not able to write to var/lib/gems/1.8 with gem install bundler)

Even after "Successfully Installed bundler" I still get "Bundle command not found" when i try to run either "gem bundle install" or "bundle install" from my App.

I think I need to change the executable but I am lost as to how to do this.

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/james/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:

Really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: so I think I installed Gems not on Root, which resulted in the installation directory ending up in var/lib/gems/1.8. Do I need to uninstall and then re-install? Really struggling with this for some dumb reason, so any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: figured it out! Really dumb, i ended giving the user write permission to var/lib/gems/1.8 and then add var/lib/gems/1.8 to the path. It says it REALLY clearly for ubuntu users in the installation I guess i just missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I cant remember exactly how I did this. It had to do with installing to the wrong directory. Adding the path on the ~/.bashrc file fixed it I am pretty sure. Try adding the lines below to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file and see if that works. These are the three bottom lines of my file.

```
export RUBYOPT="-r rubygems"
export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH

if [[ -s /home/james/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /home/james/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
```

The instructions that I used to figure this out are [here](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) also it looks like [this](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/system-wide/) might be a better way to do it, as it is a system wide installation. I would have done this if I did it over.

Also check these other posts regarding the same issue. I am sure you will be able to figure it out from there.

Good Luck!
[post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910088/how-can-i-edit-the-path-on-linux)
[post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909673/gems-and-ubuntu-9-04)