# Errors using any Heroku command

Tags: heroku

Any time I use any Heroku command I get this error. So far the commands have still worked so I haven't thought much about it:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31: command not found:  git config heroku.remote
```

However now when I try `heroku db:pull`, I get this error. Not sure if the two are related, but either way I could use help solving one or both.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.15/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.15/bin/schema:3
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:08
Receiving indexes
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.15/bin/schema:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/taps-0.3.15/bin/schema:3
schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
Receiving data
13 tables, 6,957 records
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite3/errors.rb:62:in `check': SQLite3::SQLException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (Sequel::DatabaseError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite3/resultset.rb:56:in `check'
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has some information on this [here](http://docs.heroku.com/heroku-command) (down at the bottom):

> ## Troubleshooting
>
> ### Command not found
>
> On some machines your path may not be
>   set correctly to run binary gems. If
>   you get a command not found error, you
>   need to add the rubygems executable
>   directory to your path. You can find
>   the EXECUTABLE_DIRECTORY by running
>
> `$ gem environment`
>
> And then setting
>   your path to include the appropriate
>   directory:
>
> `$ export PATH=/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090201/bin:$PATH`

And it links back to this StackOverflow article (how meta): [How do I use gems with Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909673/gems-and-ubuntu-9-04)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the other errors, but this one:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (Sequel::DatabaseError)
```

is because you are trying to insert a duplicate primary key into a table.  Not sure why that is occurring, though.