# Pry command not available (Linux Mint Maya)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pry, linux-mint

When I enter pry to start the pry gem shell my terminal (Gnome 3.4.1.1) responds:

```
$ pry
No command 'pry' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pr' from package 'coreutils' (main)
pry: command not found
```

I installed pry using `$ gem install pry`

As mentioned in the title I'm running Linux Mint Maya (13).

Comment: Did you add your gem bin path to your executable search path? Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909673/how-do-i-use-gems-with-ubuntu

Comment: I check my $PATH variable and it had the bin folder included. I actually found the reason: I had to add {[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"} to my .bashrc which i forgot installing rvm. Everthing is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you've installed pry using rbenv, then you need to run the following in you terminal.

`rbenv rehash`

rbenv caches current Ruby executables as so-called shims.

Comment: The recommended way is to install ruby using rbenv.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and resolved by typing a command in terminal:

```
rvm rubygems current
```